# Open jQuery dialog from anchor link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I've spent many hours trying to solve this issue but have yet to find any solution.

Can someone please enlighten me on how I can open a jQuery dialog from an anchor link (eg:, link)?

I have loaded jquery.min.js, jquery-ui.js, and jquery-ui.css.

Thanks, I really appreciate any help as this has been immensely frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to open a popup like from a tag that has a href attibute.

In this case, I had same problem time ago, and I solve using a JQuery plugin, [bpopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/).

```
 $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
   contentContainer:'.content',
   loadUrl: 'test.html' //Uses jQuery.load()
 });
```